# How to solve an issue with QFileDialog's filter parameter?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qfiledialog, qmediaplayer

I want to create a file dialog, using **QFileDialog**, to choose an audio file to set in **QMediaPlayer** with a file extension mask **(*.mp3, *.ogg, *.flac)**.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work as it should be taking the last extension as a filter property.

I've tried this for PyQt5 and PySide2, result is same. It shows files with the latest extension in the filter list e.g *.mp3 or *.flac only

```
audioFormats = "*.mp3, *.wav, *.ogg, *.wma, *.flac"
print(f"these are formats: {audioFormats}")
self.track, _ = self.getOpenFileName(parent=self, caption="Set track file", filter=f"Audio files ({audioFormats})")
```

I'm expected it to show files with all these extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the example of the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#details) indicates, you should not use commas to separate the extensions:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    audioFormats = "*.mp3 *.wav *.ogg *.wma *.flac" # without commas
    filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=None, 
        caption="Set track file",
        filter=audioFormats)
    if filename:
        print(filename)
```